# Why typescript do not complain when i pass const with extra key in function

Tags: typescript

I wonder why typescript do not complain when i pass const with extra key in function, but complains when i pass the same object as an object

Playground link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwCrmgXigbwFBSgQwC4oBnYOASwDsEAaXKAI2LMpvoF9tsA3fOAlAwAKfgmLxkqAJTEeAewoATIQD4sHANzd8wnHiJQA5PiP08zY4zMMAxsSO2zUAPQuoEOHHkD8JDwAekLbAECoAtFAA8gDS2BzS3LbyVGQEiAAMQlgMhiY2Fg7W5lD2xk6c2ti6YhnSru5U8h5ePlCRMVFAA)

```
type ArgType = {
  a: string,
  b: string,
}

var a = (arg: ArgType): void => {};

a({
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c', // error as expected - OK
})

const arg0 = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c',
};

a(arg0) // no error - KO
```

Comment: [Excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what i asked for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the way Typescript is designed and I don't know about the design process behind the scene but quoting straight from the Typescript docs:

```
function printLabel(labeledObj: { label: string }) {
    console.log(labeledObj.label);
}

let myObj = {size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object"};
printLabel(myObj);
```

> The type checker checks the call to printLabel. The printLabel
>   function has a single parameter that requires that the object passed
>   in has a property called label of type string. Notice that our object
>   actually has more properties than this, but the compiler only checks
>   that at least the ones required are present and match the types
>   required. There are some cases where TypeScript isn’t as lenient,
>   which we’ll cover in a bit.

But the TS compiler does [Excess Property Checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) on object literals:

> In our first example using interfaces, TypeScript lets us pass { size:
>   number; label: string; } to something that only expected a { label:
>   string; }
>
> However, combining it with optional types would allow an error to
>   sneak in. For example, taking our example using `createSquare`:

```
interface SquareConfig {
    color?: string;
    width?: number;
}

function createSquare(config: SquareConfig): { color: string; area: number } {
    // ...
}

let mySquare = createSquare({ colour: "red", width: 100 });
```

> Notice the given argument to `createSquare` is spelled `colour`
>   instead of `color`. In plain JavaScript, this sort of thing fails
>   silently.
>
> You could argue that this program is correctly typed, since the width
>   properties are compatible, there’s no color property present, and the
>   extra colour property is insignificant.
>
> However, TypeScript takes the stance that there’s probably a bug in
>   this code. Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess
>   property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing
>   them as arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the
>   “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error:

```
// error: Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'colour' does not exist in type 'SquareConfig'. Did you mean to write 'color'?
let mySquare = createSquare({ colour: "red", width: 100 });
```

And finally there are a few ways to work around this scenario:

**1.** You can use [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
let mySquare = createSquare({ width: 100, opacity: 0.5 } as SquareConfig);
```

**2.** You can first assign it to another variable then pass the variable:

```
let squareOptions = { colour: "red", width: 100 };
let mySquare = createSquare(squareOptions);
```

**3.** Another approach might be to add a string index signature if you’re sure that the object can have some extra properties that are used in some special way:

```
interface SquareConfig {
    color?: string;
    width?: number;
    [propName: string]: any;
}
```